# Only show view tab for current user profile

Tags: 7, views

I created a HTML table view to show the current "listings" the user has created. I have everything set up (I think), but I am looking in how I can restrict access. The view is suppose to be a tab on the user profile page with the title of "My Listings". I need to only show it to the profile owner and also make it so people can't access it via URL itself (bypassing the tab)

I remember this was doable back in the Drupal 6 days, but my memory fails me.

Path: /user/%/listings (contextual filter % is set to UID)

So if user 1 goes to /user/1/listings They should see a tab next to View | Edit that says "My Listings"

But if user 4 goes to /user/2/listings they shouldn't see the "My Listing" tab. But if they go to /user/4 they should see their "my listings" tab.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your view path to:

```
user/%/listings
```

Add a contextual filter of: author uid, and set 'WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL' to User ID from logged in user.

Add a menu 'Menu Tab'.

For access you have various options. Here is a simple one.

Install [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) and set access to PHP, then add this bit of code in there:

```
global $user;
return $user->uid == arg(1);
```

Comment: You can add the above mentioned PHP Code in same Contextual Filter by checking 'Specify validation criteria', then select PHP Code from Validator.

Comment: But I would still prefer some other way rather than putting PHP Code in the database.